# Sort list of different models by two fields with different type

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, interface

I have two models:

```
public class CarRent
{
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RentEndDate { get; set; }
}

public class CarPurchase
{
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public decimal Mileage { get; set; }
}
```

I need `to combine them into one list`, `group by` `CarName` and then inside each group I need `to sort` models initially by `SystemId`, but then if models have the same `SystemId` - I need `to sort` `CarRent` models by `RentEndDate` and `CarPurchase` by `Mileage`.

**What I have tried:**

I defined an interface:

```
public interface ICarPurchaseOrdered
{
    string CarName { get; }
    string SystemId { get; }
    string Order { get; }
}
```

and got my models to implement it, the `Order` property just returns string representation of second order criteria, then I defined a view model:

```
public class GroupedCardList
{
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ICarPurchaseOrdered> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

then I have a grouper that just groups my models:

```
public class CarGrouper
{
    IEnumerable<GroupedCardList> Group(IEnumerable<ICarPurchaseOrdered> cars)
    {
        return cars.GroupBy(c => c.CarName)
                   .OrderBy(c => c.Key)
                   .Select(c => new GroupedCardList()
                   {
                       CarName = c.Key,
                       Cars = c.OrderBy(n => n.SystemId)
                               .ThenBy(n => n.Order)
                   });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work right because it sorts strings and I get the car purchase with `Milage=1200` before the car with `Milage=90`.

I know that example is a little bit contrived but it perfectly represents the issue that I have right now. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Can you add a `ThenBy` for the mileage, but use `Convert.ToInt32`, or `Convert.ToDouble` if it's not an integer.

Comment: I can't do this because sometimes in the Order field I would have a string representation of DateTime from RentEndDate field. Maybe I should change Order to decimal, what do you think?

Comment: The `Order` property is a code smell. Your domain objects should not introduce a string property to be used for sorting, this is the concern of your presentation layer. Where are you displaying these items? In a `DataGridView`? Also, is it possible that you have a `CarRent` instance and a `CarPurchase` instance with the same `SystemId`? (And how do you sort in that case?)

Comment: @Groo No, I'm using it in asp.net mvc project and displaying it in simple view. The issue is to group models by one criteria and then sort them depending on type of model.

Comment: So is it possible to have a `CarRent` instance and a `CarPurchase` instance with the same SystemId? How you do deal with that case?

Comment: @Groo Yes, it is. Just imagine that it's kind of subtype of car.

Comment: But how do you compare them in that case? You still haven't specified how to handle this case. How do you compare a `CarRent { Id=5, RentEndDate=05/05/2014 }` and a `CarPurchase { Id=5, Mileage=100000 }`?

Comment: @Groo It doesn't really matter how to compare different types, thank you for the answer I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to implement a custom `IComparer`. If you extract a common base class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}

public class CarRent : Car
{
    public DateTime RentEndDate { get; set; }
}

public class CarPurchase : Car
{
    public decimal Mileage { get; set; }
}
```

Then a `IComparer<Car>` implementation might look like this:

```
public class CarComparer : IComparer<Car>
{
    public int Compare(Car x, Car y)
    {
        // compare by system id first
        var order = string.Compare(x.SystemId, y.SystemId);
        if (order != 0)
            return order;

        // try to cast both items as CarRent
        var xRent = x as CarRent;
        var yRent = y as CarRent;
        if (xRent != null && yRent != null)
            return DateTime.Compare(xRent.RentEndDate, yRent.RentEndDate);

        // try to cast both items as CarPurchase
        var xPurc = x as CarPurchase;
        var yPurc = y as CarPurchase;
        if (xPurc != null && yPurc != null)
            return decimal.Compare(xPurc.Mileage, yPurc.Mileage);

        // now, this is awkward
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can then pass the comparer instance to [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: So, to clarify, you would simply write `Cars = c.OrderBy(x => x, new CarComparer())`, without the need for `ThenBy`. If there is a large number of different classes and properties, there might be a way to generalize it using reflection (to avoid manual plumbing for each derived type), but that would probably be better suited for another question.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. +1 for 'now, this is awkward'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int.Parse` and order *integers* instead of *strings*

```
c.OrderBy(n => n.SystemId)
  .ThenBy(n => int.Parse(n.Order))
```

Comment: yes, but how should I treat requirement with sorting by RentEndDate if I have models of type CarRent? Maybe I should change the type of Order to decimal and just get Ticks of RentEndDate? But for CarPurchase it would just return Mileage?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the most logical comparison between a decimal and DateTime and also they are semantically different

Comment: Yes, it seems like they should be addressed separately.

Answer (score 0):

The `ICarPurchaseOrdered.Order` used to order (then) by is a string type; Hence why the ordering is done alphabetically.

I would suggest to change the type of `ICarPurchaseOrdered.Order` to `object`,
so the Orderby`can use the underlying object (either`DateTime`or`Decimal`) to order.

**Update:
Try this

```
c.OrderBy(n => n.SystemId)
 .ThenBy(n => n.GetType())
 .ThenBy(n => n.Order);
```

Comment: Good point, but it throws an exception: System.ArgumentException : Object must be of type DateTime.
   at System.DateTime.CompareTo(Object value)
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)